# DynamicReports - Chart Hyperlinks

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I wanted to know how to add a Hyperlink to a Pie Chart Pie.
I am using Dynamic Reports and Jasper.

Regards
Mithil

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a sectionHyperlink like this:

```
 <pieDataset>
  <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERS_SHIPCOUNTRY}]]></keyExpression>
    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERS_FREIGHT}.doubleValue()]]></valueExpression>
    <labelExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Formatter().format("%20.2f",$F{ORDERS_FREIGHT}.doubleValue()).toString().trim()]]></labelExpression>
    **<sectionHyperlink hyperlinkType="Reference">
        <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://www.stackoverflow.com"]]>     
        </hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
        <hyperlinkParameter name="report_count">
        <hyperlinkParameterExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]>
        </hyperlinkParameterExpression>
        </hyperlinkParameter>
      </sectionHyperlink>**
</pieDataset>
```

There are more options. As far as I know, Dynamic Reports should have no affect to this.